# IcCube add Custom attributes to Data Source Table?

Tags: iccube

Is there are way we can add Custom Fields to the Tables sourced from MSSQL in icCube.
My requirement is to use a CASE Statement and generate a new custom attribute in the SQL Table ?

Answer (score 0):

Next to adding plain tables ans views from MySql in icCube, you can create a  query on the MySql connection in plain MySql language.